# Remove prefixes from variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I'm working on a project where previous developer used some non standard naming scheme that he coded into resharper where almost all identifiers have prefixes. All local variables start with `tmp`, parameters start with `in` or `out`, etc. How can I globally apply renaming to the variables, specifically change:

`tmpMyVariable` into `myVariable`

`inMyParameter` into `myParameter`

`m_Field` into `_field`

Comment: Have you tried using the build in refactoring tool VS provides? Right click object rename..Other than that and find and replace (which wont work here), you will probably have to go by hand or write a regex.

Comment: @Botonomous That would involve renaming every variable one at a time, rather than being able to apply this change to all variables all at once.

Comment: @Servy I didn't say it was a good solution.

Comment: I need to do this globally. It's got over 15k lines of code, and thousands of files. I can probably get this done using PowerGrep but it would treat things as pure text rather then code, so there's potential for errors, plus it would target things like comments, strings, etc, possibly producing nasty side effects.

Comment: You could tell ReSharper to use `_` as the field naming convention and then tell it to fix all rule violations in the solution, but without trying it I'm not sure whether that would remove the leading `m` or just add another underscore before it. I don't think it could help you with the camelCase pseudo-Hungarian prefixes, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extensive research on this I ended up writing a Roslyn script that could process code semantics and not just treat it as text. Final code (it's ugly because I was writing this as a one time throw away). A few files required manual fixes because of name collisions. Fields I renamed with Resharper, so the code only targets variables and parameters.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

  var solutionPath = @"D:\Development\lams\src\Lams.sln";
  var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
  var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;

  var documents = solution.Projects.SelectMany(x => x.Documents).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();


  foreach (var documentId in documents)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(solution.GetDocument(documentId).Name);
    while (true)
    {
      var doc = solution.GetDocument(documentId);
      var model = doc.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
      var syntax = doc.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result;
      var parameters = syntax.DescendantNodes()
        .OfType<ParameterSyntax>()
        .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Identifier.ValueText, @"(in|tmp|out)([A-Z])(\w+)"))
        .ToList();


      Console.Write($"{parameters.Count} ");
      var parameter = parameters.FirstOrDefault();
      if (parameter == null)
        break;
      string name = parameter.Identifier.ValueText;
      name = Regex.Replace(name, @"(in|tmp|out)([A-Z])(\w+)", m => m.Groups[2].Value.ToLower() + m.Groups[3].Value.ToString());
      var symbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(parameter);

      solution = Renamer.RenameSymbolAsync(solution, symbol, name, null).Result;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
  }

  foreach (var documentId in documents)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(solution.GetDocument(documentId).Name);
    while (true)
    {
      var doc = solution.GetDocument(documentId);
      var model = doc.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
      var syntax = doc.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result;
      var variables = syntax.DescendantNodes()
        .OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>().SelectMany(x => x.Variables)
        .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Identifier.ValueText, @"(in|tmp|out)([A-Z])(\w+)"))
        .ToList();


      Console.Write($"{variables.Count} ");
      var variable = variables.FirstOrDefault();
      if (variable == null)
        break;
      string name = variable.Identifier.ValueText;
      name = Regex.Replace(name, @"(in|tmp|out)([A-Z])(\w+)", m => m.Groups[2].Value.ToLower() + m.Groups[3].Value.ToString());
      var symbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(variable);

      solution = Renamer.RenameSymbolAsync(solution, symbol, name, null).Result;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
  }


  //var canChange = solution.Workspace.CanApplyChange(ApplyChangesKind.ChangeDocument);
  solution.Workspace.TryApplyChanges(solution);

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Press `Ctrl + Shift + H` and place `tmp` (With a blank space at the beginning  to prevent replacing `tmp` from a middle of a word)in the first field and nothing in the other field.

`Ctrl + H` Searches and replace in the current file
`Ctrl + Shift + H` Searches and replace in the current project

Comment: This would match things other than identifiers (such as string literals, which shouldn't change).  Additionally, not all uses of every identifier will begin with a space.  For example `SomeMethod(tmpAnnoyingVariableName);` doesn't have a space preceeding `tmp`.

Comment: You need to do the process of searching and replace more than once to get it right. First you search for ` tmp` with space then `(tmp` then `=tmp` an so on.

Comment: a) this solution wouldn't lower case the letter following tmp
b) it would target non identifiers in comments/strings/etc
c) variables that are just called tmp would be completely removed making code non compilable

Comment: I just see more problem and no other ideas...
Another solution could be to make a code that process all the text searching for var definitions and store the string name of the ones that start with tmp then search that in all the code and remove the tmp and lower case the first letter.